# For all $x$ in the set of reals, $ |x-2| > 2 \implies x^2 > 4x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do i go on proving this statement?

The first step i took was to assume the antecedent. so..

assume $|x-2| > 2$

then $x > 4$ or $x < 0$

if we assume the consequence, $x^2 > 4x$

then we know that $x > 4$ and $x < 0$

They both have the same intervals for when it's true so is that enough to prove the
statement? how would i make this a well structured proof?

Comment: Please don't use the title as the first line of your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can square both sides of your inequality since they are positive:

$$\begin{align}
|x-2| &> 2 \\
(x-2)^2 &> 4 \\
x^2 - 4x + 4 &> 4 \\
x^2 &> 4x
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Simplest way (+1).

Comment: Personally I would add that the first step is $\Rightarrow$, and all other are equivalences.  That makes it immediately clear that this argument cannot be reversed.

Comment: The first step is also equivalence because $|x-2|\ge 0$ and $2\ge 0$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla You are right, of course, I stand corrected.  (I've also corrected my answer on this question.)  My point remains the same, however: it is very helpful to explicitly write down implications or equivalences.

Answer (score 0):

No. The logic here is wrong. You can't assume the consequence can you? Contradicts the very meaning of the word doesn't it? You *arrive* at the consequence.

You've begun well enough I guess. $\left|{x - 2}\right| \gt 2 \implies 4 \lt  x $ or $x \lt 0 $

***Hint:***

Now consider $(x^2 - 4x) = x(x - 4)$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this proof, longer but more mechanical, in case you don't immediately see the trick of squaring both sides in the left hand inequality.

For any $\;x\;$ the left hand inequality simplifies to
\begin{align}
& |x-2| > 2 \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"one possible definition of $\;|\quad|\;$"} \\
& (x-2)\text{ max }(-x+2) > 2 \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"property of $\;\text{max}\;$"} \\
& x-2 > 2 \;\lor\; -x+2 > 2 \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"simplify"} \\
(*)\;\;\;\phantom{\equiv} & x > 4 \;\lor\; x < 0 \\
\end{align}

For the right hand inequality we quickly get:
\begin{align}
& x^2 > 4x \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"divide by $\;x\;$, splitting in three cases"} \\
& (x < 0 \land x < 4) \;\lor\; (x = 0 \land 0^2 > 4 \times 0) \;\lor\; (x > 0 \land x > 4) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"simplify: ordering; middle part is false; ordering"} \\
(**)\;\;\;\phantom{\equiv} & x < 0 \;\lor\; x > 4 \\
\end{align}

Now from $(*)$ and $(**)$ it is clear that both inequalities are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

What you *said* is wrong.

However, $|x -2| > 2$ *if and only if* $x < 0$ or $x > 4$.

Similarly, $x^2 > 4x$ *if and only if* $x < 0$ or $x > 4$.

If you had realized that fact, then you could conclude that $|x-2|>2$ *if and only if* $x^2 > 4x$.

From your words, it sounds like you did the work to show that both of those statements were "if and only if" statements, but hadn't thought through the logic of what you had shown.